# State income taxes when traveling to another state

Tags: united-states, california, state-income-tax, florida

I live and work in CA for an employer in San Francisco, but I travel often to FL and work there remotely for a total of perhaps 2-3 months a year. Am I supposed to pay state income taxes to CA during those months even though I am earning income and working in FL?

Comment: Does this question address your concern? https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/117522/meal-and-grocery-deductions-for-long-business-trips

Comment: @dwizum it does not. The question you referenced talks about business deductions when traveling to other states. I am asking about how W2 income is taxed at the state level when I travel to other states

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The good news is, Florida doesn't have a state income tax, so you owe Florida nothing.

The bad news is, California's tax law says that you're taxed on all income earned from the State while you're a resident or part-time resident (which you appear to qualify as)

[Source](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/forms/2018/18_1031.pdf)

TL;DR: You owe Cali taxes 365 days a year on all income generated from a source in the State of California (IE your job).

If you were less lucky, you might owe taxes in two states at the same time as a part-time resident of one and an earner in another.

Comment: that's what I thought. Thank you!

Comment: I can personally confirm that this answer is correct. In my case it was CA and TX.